# Community HTTPS Auto-Edit Incorrectly Shown In Revision History

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, revision-history, community-user

*First bug report & meta post, and a rare poster. I appreciate any help in title, tags, terminology or else. If duplicate, searching tips would be welcome.*

If you check revision 5 of [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44050186/revisions), you'll see automated [Community ♦] user correcting one instance of "*http*" to "*https*" in the very end of that revision. It shows fine for "*side-by-side markdown*".

For "*inline*" or "*side-by-side*" however, it messes up and shows **the removal of the whole URL, and then the addition of the question title of that URL**.

Cross-checked current question version with the currently last revision history item (#5) to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a side-effect of how full urls are replaced by their titles *on rendering*. It's not worth spending CPU time looking up titles for old-style `http://` links.

If you include `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table` in a post, the title for that link is looked up and shown instead of the link. However (and this is the important bit) this *only works for `https://` URLs now*.

So the rendering is correct; old-style `http://` links are not supported anymore so are not shown as the title, while new-style `https://` links do get the treatment.

Comment: That raises a few questions: (1) This replacement feature, is it a property of SE websites? Or is it a property of something underlying/superceding? (2) Why is there a higher resource usage to process "*http*"? (3) Shouldn't it be a *desirable* goal to have the line diff. comparisons more consistent? (*granted, feasibility, cost, etc. govern our actions, but not our desires. Didn't read/notice feasibility remarks yet though.*)

Comment: @KtX2SkD: it's a property of SE websites.

Comment: @KtX2SkD: there is no point in rendering `http://` links, since this edit just replaced them all. Everything is https-only now, so why waste CPU resources and code on detecting those links?

Comment: Yeah picture's clearing up now: Bot's repairing deprecated material, revision gets messed up. You can fix revision by supporting deprecated material, but, **that is the whole point**: You are aiming to deprecate this thing, continuing to support it is the exact opposite of deprecation, and a bad investment when much enough of the material is updated.